# Rampart Client throwing exception when trying to consume the service

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, webservice-client

I am trying to invoke a axis2 web service enabled with Rampart security. When I try to invoke the service through the client I am getting the following exception, (I have also included Jaxen Jar in my project)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/JaxenException
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:446)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at com.tcs.secure.SecureServiceStub.add(SecureServiceStub.java:186)
    at com.tcs.secure.Client.main(Client.java:16)
```

I have generated stubs for my password call back class and my sample class and imported it to my client. Here is my sample client.

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
        SecureServiceStub stub = new SecureServiceStub();

        Add request = new Add();
        request.setA(23);
        request.setB(389);

        AddResponse response = stub.add(request);
        System.out.println(response);

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running the client, I mean from command prompt or from some IDE ?

Comment: I am running it through eclipse..

Comment: this exception has occurred at the server side. Please check the server side errors. Have you put compatible axis2 and rampart versions?

Comment: Hi Amila I solved the issue with Jaxen. But getting exception like Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.lang.RuntimeException: Undefined 'Security policy namespace cannot be null.' resource property when I try to invoke the service..

Comment: Please attach your security policy - and the SOAP message being sent to the server.. You use tcpmon to capture the request...

Comment: @SSG how did you solve the "Security policy namespace cannot be null" issue?